# what are cookies? Is it a kind of local storage?

Tags: cookies, storage

What kind of storage the cookies is. I am stuck in the question. Is it a storage like local storage? How it works and ways to stay safe?
what are cookies used for?
where are cookies stored?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### What are cookies?

- HTTP cookies are small blocks of data created by a web server while a user is browsing a website and placed on the user's computer or other device by the user's web browser. Cookies are placed on the device used to access a website, and more than one cookie may be placed on a user's device during a session.

### What are they used for?

- When you visit a website, your web server transfers a small packet of data to your device's browser: a computer cookie. This cookie is designed to remember information about you, including a record of your website visits and activity.

### Are some browser cookies harmful?

- Since the data in cookies doesn't change, cookies themselves aren't harmful. They can't infect computers with viruses or other malware. However, some cyberattacks can hijack cookies and enable access to your browsing sessions. The danger lies in their ability to track individuals' browsing histories.

### Where are browser cookies stored?

- In the browser lol